# React => Make action on back button on Android Google Chrome (Not React Native)

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs

I have a case where there is the application written in React (not React Native).

The application runs on the web. So for example I use Google Chrome on my mobile (android).

I'm on some URL in my app. Is it possible to add some action when the user clicks the 'back icon'? To move to the previous page for example?

I know that we can easily achieve it on React Native, but in just React?

I mean this back icon:

[image]

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use React Router there is a hook called `useHistory` you can use it go back in React

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useHistory
} from "react-router-dom";

const Foo = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={history.goBack}>Back</button>
      <p>foo</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const Bar = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={history.goBack}>Back</button>
      <p>bar</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/foo">foo</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/bar">bar</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/foo" children={<Foo />} />
          <Route path="/bar" children={<Bar />} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

for more details on this you follow this [docs page](https://thewebdev.info/2021/09/18/how-to-go-back-to-the-previous-page-with-react-router-v5/)

Comment: Thanks @sarthak but I mean something different. I updated my question. Please check it